# Formula stopped working after changing date field to calculated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, date-time

Why do I get different results for `B2` and `C2`?

[image]

Here are the two formulas:

0:00 = `=SUMIFS(tblTrack[Spent],tblTrack[Time Ended],">="&E9)`

6:32 = `=SUMIFS(tblTrack[Spent],tblTrack[Time Ended],">="&F9)`

As you can see the only difference is the column for the reference.

Here's the formula view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The NOW() function also has a current time component as apposed to TODAY() which is just the date, so they are actually different numbers.  This will no doubt affect your calculations, but how exactly is hard for me to tell based on the spreadsheet provided.

Edit - looking through your edits I suspect your use of the NOW() function to represent the dates might be the problem, perhaps using the TODAY() function in them might resolve it.